# In jqGrid is there a way to reference asp.net mvc model in the colModel section?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, jqgrid

I've tried searching for dynamic as well and haven't found the answer i'm looking for.

Basically i'm trying to declare a grid with the `editoption: { readonly: '@Model.IsReadOnly' }` instead of having it hardcoded to `editoption: { readonly: false }`

But i don't think jqGrid recognizes `editoption: { readonly: 'false' }` which what the code evaluates too.

Is there a way to reference a mvc model without the `''`?

Code snippet of what works and doesn't work

`colModel: [
                { name: 'AccountCode', index: 'AccountCode', width: 50, align: "left", editable: true, editoptions: { readonly: '@Model.IsAccountCodeReadOnly' } },  // does not work
                { name: 'AccountDesc', index: 'AccountDesc', width: 80, align: "left", editable: true, editoptions: { readonly: '@Model.IsAccountDescReadOnly' } },  // does not work
                { name: 'UserDefine1', index: 'UserDefine1', width: 20, align: "left", editable: true, editoptions: { readonly: 'false' } },  // does not work
                { name: 'UserDefine2', index: 'UserDefine2', width: 20, align: "left", editable: true, editoptions: { readonly: false } }  // works
            ],`

Hope im asking the right question.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anybody else has a similiar question.  I ended up just creating a few variables before the jqgrid designer is called.

`var isAccountCodeReadOnly = '@Model.IsAccountCodeReadOnly'.toLowerCase() == 'false';`

`colModel: [
            { name: 'AccountCode', index: 'AccountCode', width: 50, align: "left", editable: true, editoptions: { readonly: isAccountCodeReadOnly } },
.....
]`

and so on for any number of columns defined in the colModel that needs this check done.

Not pretty but it works.